# How to compile two C# codes

Tags: c#, compilation

I have 2 C# codes, file1.cs and file2.cs. file2.cs uses the properties, methods and fields form file1.cs. How can I compile this code? I am not using Visual Studio. From online research it seems like both the files have to be in the same project. How do I accomplish this using command line as I am not using Visual Studio?

Right now when I compile file1.cs like `csc file1.cs` it says

```
error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

This makes sens as file1.cs does not have any Main method. The Main method exists in file2.cs. When I compile file2 .cs like this `csc file2.cs` it says

```
error CS0103: The name 'MyCusVals' does not exist in the current context
warning CS0168: The variable 'Vals' is declared but never used
```

Both MycusVals and Vals are defined in file1.cs which is sitting in the same directory as file2.cs
What is the correct syntax to compile file2.cs so that it can see file1.cs

Comment: You can also use something like `msbuild.exe mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"`.

Comment: You need to compile them together.  The `csc` command will compile a list of C# files all grouped together on the command line.  Life, by the way, is much easier with Visual Studio.  There's a free version you can download

Comment: You can still download the v2 .NET SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988 (and, that stuff should compile with a Framework 3.5.1 environment).  I'm not sure about the v2 version, but the v1.0 and v1.1 versions just used `csc` and make files (I know - I actually wrote them when I worked for Microsoft).  You could take a look at how those work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @Flydog57. However, I still get the error. I tried this `csc file2.cs file1.cs`. But I still get error`error CS0103: The name 'MyCusVals' does not exist in the current context`
`warning CS0168: The variable 'Vals' is declared but never used`

Comment: Without seeing the code for your two files, it's hard to tell what the issue is.  You got rid of one of the errors!

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57. Yes one of the error was gone and the remaining went away too once I started proof reading. Simple typos. Thanks again. How can I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile them together. The `csc` command will compile a list of C# files all grouped together on the command line. Life, by the way, is much easier with Visual Studio. There's a free version you can download.

You can still download the v2 .NET SDK: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19988 (and, that stuff should compile with a Framework 3.5.1 environment). I'm not sure about the v2 version, but the v1.0 and v1.1 versions just used `csc.exe` and `make` files. You could take a look at how those work